# GIT clone fails: "git-upload-pack" isn't allowed to be executed. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

when trying to clone from a SLES11 Server I get the following error message:

```
"git-upload-pack" isn't allowed to be executed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried two different clients so far. Nothing worked. I tried to clone via SSH. The server has git version 1.6.0.2 installed, the clients 1.7.4.1 and 1.7.3.4

Since I didn't find any references about that problem so far I'm asking here for help. Does anybody know this problem? Are there any settings I could try?

Thanks a lot for any advise in advance.

cu
Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused through sudosh, a shell wrapper logging everything thats typed. I can use git with SLES as soon as I turn this thing off. That would mean ssh is not a viable option in my case, even so its the only one I have in this place. The problem is therefore unsolvable in this particular case. Shame.

Answer (score 1):

i suffered the same problem today. and searched it in google. finely i got here.
from your info "The problem seems to be caused through sudosh" .   so i checked the sodush and it's conf file.   finely  the problem was resolved.
here are two resolution;
1:  form user side ,  exchange user to others whose shell is not sudosh.or change user's shell

```
one:x:501:500::/home/one:/usr/local/bin/sudosh //in passwd file
```

2:  edit the /etc/sudosh.conf file.   add your cmd to as allow.
     below is a sample file of sudosh.conf

```
# Sudosh Configuration File 
logdir = /var/log/sudosh 
default shell = /bin/bash 
delimiter = - 
syslog.priority = LOG_INFO 
syslog.facility = LOG_LOCAL2
#clearenvironment = yes
# Allow Sudosh to execute -c arguments? If so, what?
-c arg allow = scp
-c arg allow = rsync
#-c arg allow = /bin/bash
```

Answer (score -1):

The executable `git-upload-pack` is not allowed to be executed. Either your `git-shell` forbids its execution, the file does not exist (in `/usr/bin/…`), its executable flag is not set, `git-daemon` is not configured to allow `upload-pack` or another obscure problem …

Which protocol are you using? Maybe try one of the other options: git, ssh, http(s)

Comment: I think the reason for this error lies within the fact that the servers can't establish an outgoing ssh connection due to firewall rules. So far it looks as if that could not be solved with any other protocol than http, which is not an option at this point.